# Can get 3200Mhz from 2 RAM sticks but unable to get 3200Mhz from 4 RAM sticks

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I am using Gigabyte B450 Aorus Pro Wifi motherbard, AMD Ryzen 7 2600x, Corsair DDR4 2x8GB 3200Mhz RAM (CMK16GX4M2B3200C16). My OS is Windows 10 64-bit.

In the previous set-up, I had 2 RAM sticks(16Gbyte) onto RAM slots #1 and #2. On the Bios, I chose XMP profile. I had no problem getting 3200Mhz clock from the RAM sticks. Recently, I bought another 2 RAM sticks of the exact model (CMK16GX4M2B3200C16). Strangely, the RAM clock speed dropped to 2100Mhz.

Any idea what else I can do to get back 3200Mhz clock speed from RAM?

Comment: That is not unusual. The maximum supported RAM speed with two modules/ranks is always higher than with 4.

Comment: Ok. I think next time, I'll get single RAM stick of 16GByte instead of 8Gbyte.

Comment: And additionally make sure that the stick is "single rank". A "dual rank" module is from the perspective of the CPU like two sticks glued together.

Comment: So, if I use 4 "dual rank" sticks, CPU sees it as 8 sticks?

Comment: AFAIK yes. And as desktop CPUs usually only supports 4 sticks it will not work. Check your mainboard manual for supported memory configurations.